# Polybase Insert into External table failed - Path does not exist - SQL Server 2016 RC3

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, sql-server-2016

I tested Polybase with SQL Server 2016 RC3 Developer:

- I am able to create external data sources
- I can create file formats
- I created external tables pointing to my Hadoop file system
- I can run select over my external tables and get the data in Management Studio
- However, when I try to insert into the same tables I get the following error:

'Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.Common.ErrorHandling.MppSqlException: EXTERNAL TABLE access failed because the specified path name ''hdfs://localhost:9000/input/OldSales.csv'' does not exist. Enter a valid path and try again'

I am sure the path exist, moreover, if I am able to select the same external table, the external source contains the right path, or I am missing something?

This is my insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[OldTrasactions]
SELECT TOP 1000 
       [SalesOrderNumber]
      ,[SalesOrderLineNumber]
      ,p.EnglishProductName as ProductName
      ,st.SalesTerritoryCountry
      ,[OrderQuantity]
      ,[UnitPrice]
      ,[ExtendedAmount]
      ,[SalesAmount]
      ,convert(date,[OrderDate]) AS [OrderDate]
  FROM [AdventureworksDW2016CTP3].[dbo].[FactInternetSales] a
  inner join dbo.DimProduct p on a.ProductKey = p.ProductKey
  inner join dbo.DimSalesTerritory st on st.SalesTerritoryKey = a.SalesTerritoryKey
  where year(OrderDate) < 2011
```

I also enable polybase export:

```
sp_configure 'allow polybase export', 1;
reconfigure
```

It seems like there is a permission problem and I am getting wrong error message.

Other details:

- Windows Server 2012
- Hadoop 2.7.1 (single node)

Any comment will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

For export using polybase, please ensure that the specified path is a directory which exists or can be created, and that files can be created in that directory.

Refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt652313.aspx for more details.